# Remove unnecessary joins in CakePHP 3 pagination

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I have two tables:

```
Books
    id
    publisher_id
Publishers
    id
    name
```

Books is associated with Publishers in the `BooksTable` class like so:

```
public function initialize(array $config){
    $this->belongsTo('Publishers');
}
```

I want to display a list of books along with their publishers, here is my code:

```
$query = $this->Books->find()
    ->contain('Publishers')
    ->select(['id', 'title', 'Publishers.name']);
$this->paginate($query);
```

This works fine, however I noticed that it produces the following queries:

```
SELECT * FROM books Books
    LEFT JOIN publishers Publishers ON Publishers.id = (Books.publisher_id)
    ORDER BY Books.id desc LIMIT 20 OFFSET 0
SELECT (COUNT(*)) AS `count` FROM books Books
    LEFT JOIN publishers Publishers ON Publishers.id = (Books.publisher_id)
```

The Pagination component automatically strips out the unneeded code such as `GROUP`, `ORDER`, etc. from the second count query but it keeps the `LEFT JOIN`.
Is there a reason why this isn't removed and is there a way to tell it to ignore certain associations when querying the row count?

Comment: `LEFT JOIN` is needed because when your perform left join your row count **greater** or equal to LEFT Table's row count. so it does correct. If you need example let me know.

Comment: could you explain, isn't the publisher simply extra data? I don't see how it will affect the row count.

Comment: Please see answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Say for example following is data for your table.

```
Books

id | publisher_id
-----------------
1  | 1
2  | 1

Publishers    
id | name
----------
1 | publisher1
1 | publisher2

LEFT JOIN output
book_id | publisher_id | name
-----------------------
1 | 1 | publisher1
1 | 1 | publisher2
2 | 1  | publisher1
2 | 1 | publisher2
```

I know, For your case publisher_id is unique. but that's not case all time. Now you can see that LEFT JOIN has row count 4 while only 2 book there.

Comment: OK thanks, I never thought of the case where publisher_id is not unique. I will mark this as the answer but if you or anyone else could comment I would still like to know if there is a way to tell CakePHP to exclude joins that we know will be unique.

Comment: @cmann I wish i can help you with that, but i don't know cakePHP.

Answer (score 0):

This question was asked years ago about CakePHP3, but there is a method for CakePHP4. You can pass in a function to `$query->counter()` to override the default counting method. So you can tell Cake to run the query without the joins, for example:

`$query = $query->counter(function($q) {return $this->Books->find()->count();});`

See https://book.cakephp.org/4/en/orm/query-builder.html#returning-the-total-count-of-records